# Find unique tuples in Pyspark RDD

Tags: python, apache-spark, mapreduce, pyspark

I have an rdd of user activity data on a shopping platform in pyspark as:

**user_id**  |   **product_id**  |   **Event** (Viewed product, purchased, added to cart etc)

The thing is there can be multiple event types for same (user_id, product_id) tuple. And I would like to collect all such events in same row.

Example:

```
╔═════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ user_id    |  product_id             |   Event  ║
╠═════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 1               1                     viewed    ║
║ 1               1                     purchased ║
║ 2               1                     added     ║
║ 2               2                     viewed    ║
║ 2               2                     added     ║
╚═════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

I want:

```
╔════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ user_id | product_id |      Event              ║
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 1          1          {viewed, purchased}      ║
║ 2          1          {added}                  ║
║ 2          2          {viewed, added}          ║
╚════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

Comment: Have you looked into using the built-in `map` and `groupByKey` functions?

Answer (score 0):

in Scala it should look like this:

```
val grouped : RDD[((user_id, product_id), Iterable[Event])]= rdd.map(triplet => ((triplet._1, triplet._2), triplet._3)).groupByKey()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to try `Dataframe` the look at this:-

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
rdd = sc.parallelize([[1, 1, 'viewed'],[1, 1, 'purchased'],[2, 1, 'added'],[2, 2, 'viewed'],[2, 2, 'added']])
df = rdd.toDF(['user_id', 'product_id', 'Event'])
df.groupby(['user_id', 'product_id']).agg(F.collect_set("Event")).show()
```

If likes to follow `rdd` the look for this:-

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([[1, 1, 'viewed'],[1, 1, 'purchased'],[2, 1, 'added'],[2, 2, 'viewed'],[2, 2, 'added']])
rdd.groupBy(lambda x:(x[0],x[1])).map(lambda x:(x[0][0], x[0][1], map(lambda x:x[2], list(x[1])) )).collect()
```